# How to show full text in scroll view in Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm writing view that should contain multiline text, I use scroll view to scroll it, but it also wraps my text. Modifiers like .lineLimit(nil) doesn't work.

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView{
        Text(lesson.text)
    }
}
```

So it is screenshots without and with scroll view.

[image: without scroll view]

[image: with scroll view]

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. please provide more information.

Answer (score 9):

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView{
        Text(lesson.text)
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
    }
}
```

should solve the problem.

This is default in iOS 13.1 and above.